# Unable to copy from a set sheet when looping through data

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I had an earlier question which was kindly answered and I was given the following code which worked perfectly in a test environment where the code was looping through 3 sheets with only 1 sheet of data and 3 columns.

Below is my ammended code to go through 16 columns. The issue however I believe I am facing is when opening a sheet in the live environment the sub workbooks all contain 4 tabs which are "Lookup", "Detail", "Summary" and "Calls".

The code contains `For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`

I am wanting to only take the data in the below code from each workbook in the loop in the "Calls" tab. Can anyone recommend any change to the existing loop to do this?

```
Sub Theloopofloops()

 Dim wbk As Workbook
 Dim Filename As String
 Dim path As String
 Dim rCell As Range
 Dim rRng As Range
 Dim wsO As Worksheet
 Dim sheet As Worksheet
 Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet2)

 path = "M:\Documents\Call Logger\"
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.xlsm")
 Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")


 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
     DoEvents
     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, True, True)
            For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                Set rRng = sheet.Range("A2:A20000")
                For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
                If rCell <> "" And rCell.Value <> vbNullString And rCell.Value <> 0 Then


                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rCell
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 1)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 2)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 3)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 4)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 5)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 6)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 7)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 8)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 9)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 10)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 11)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 12).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 12)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 13).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 13)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 14).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 14)
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 15).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 15)

                End If
                Next rCell
         Next sheet
     wbk.Close False
     Filename = Dir
 Loop
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be after what follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Theloopofloops()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim wsO As Worksheet

    path = "M:\Documents\Call Logger\"
    Filename = Dir(path & "*.xlsm")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

    Do While Len(Filename) > 0
        DoEvents
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, True, True)
            For Each rCell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calls").Range("A2:A20000")
                If rCell <> "" And rCell.Value <> vbNullString And rCell.Value <> 0 Then
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 16).Value = rCell.Resize(, 16).Value
                End If
            Next rCell
        wbk.Close False
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the loop, just replace the `For Each sheet ...` line with

```
Set sheet = wbk.Worksheets("Calls")
```

(and remove `Next sheet`)

You could even shorten that and use

```
Set rRng = wbk.Worksheets("Calls").Range("A2:A20000")
```

or even skip that and use

```
For Each rCell In wbk.Worksheets("Calls").Range("A2:A20000").Cells
```

---

You can also shorten the copying by using

```
wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 16).Value = rCell.Resize(1, 16).Value
```

Comment: + My thoughts exactly.  Why loop through each sheet if your only using one.

Comment: Thanks guys makes sense. Do you know of a way that i can speed up the import? My format is that I have 1 Mastersheet, then in a dir of 11 wkbks with 4 tabs, (I am only wanting data from one tab "Calls" and in that tab the data that is in "Table1". My old code was very quick at getting the information across however when pasting the dates into mastersheet the format changed from UK to American so the 1st of December was being pasted as the 12th of January. By doing it this way it seems as though the data is pasting correctly but the code works slowly. Please advise if anyone has the answer